# Timeshift back up destination

Tags: backup

Wondering if anyone had any experience with Timeshift. I can't seem to back up directly to my SD Card, it will back up to /timeshift/ folder and I'm having to copy the back ups over to my external device. Wondering if anyone had a simple fix...